# Apache alias with <Location />

Tags: apache-2.4

I currently have a python project running on my apache server using the setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    <Location />
        SetHandler uwsgi-handler
        uWSGISocket /run/uwsgi/app/site/socket
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I have a few URLs that i don't want to go through the uwsgi handler. I've tried using Alias but it seems to be overriden by <Location /> when i do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    Alias /file.name /var/www/site/static/file.name
    <Location />
        SetHandler uwsgi-handler
        uWSGISocket /run/uwsgi/app/site/socket
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried a bunch of variation (different location/alias order, ProxyPass, rewrites) but every time <Location /> takes precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to the order of precedence in which sections within the configuration are merged. `Location` happens last and Apache `Location` directives are matched in [order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) so you need something to unset uwsgi for the some parts like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/wwww/site/static
    <Location />
        SetHandler uwsgi-handler
        uWSGISocket /run/uwsgi/app/site/socket
    </Location>
     <Location /file.name>
        SetHandler none
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```